# Google saying Malware on site, I have searched and run scans but can't find it

Tags: wordpress, malware, google-search-console

I'm having issues with google saying there's Malware on a wordpress site i manage, but I can't find it. They are rejecting all adverts linking to the site. The site is clean in google search console and also when I do a scan in Sucuri and Wordfence.

They have given me a list of files that they say contain Malware, including some .jpg files and also the .ico file and the css and js files they have listed look fine to me when I examine the code by hand.

They have also given me two urls that they say the site is linking to, but I can't find them anywhere. I've done a search on the code and the database and they're not coming up.

I'm running out of ideas now as to what the problem is and how to fix it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**Request a review of your website**

Once you are certain that any malware and backdoors have been removed from your website, request a review from Google.

1. Open Google Search Console (log in or create an account)
2. If you haven’t added or verified your website, do it now
3. Navigate to the Security Issues tab
4. Review the issues to ensure they have all been addressed
5. Check the box to confirm I have fixed these issues
6. Click Request Review
7. Give Google details of how you cleaned your website

It’s important to understand that your website will only be eligible for one review every 30 days. If you haven’t successfully removed the malware from your website, a failed review may mean a long wait